# Keyboard and animation issue in SwiftUI

Tags: animation, swiftui

I have a simple animation

```
Capsule()
    .cornerRadius(25)
    .scaleEffect(pulsate ? 1 : 1.2)
    .animation(Animation.easeInOut(duration: 1).repeatForever(autoreverses: true).speed(1.5))
    .foregroundColor(Color.red)
    .frame(width: 75, height: 27)
    .onAppear{
        self.pulsate.toggle()
    }
```

Everything works fine and the animation too. But if I open a keyboard, when I close it my view capsule starts jumping instead of just doing the scale effect only.
I really have no idea why and how to solve
Thank you all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `value` for animation

---

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var pulsate: Bool = Bool()

    @State private var stringOfText: String = String()
    
    var body: some View {

        Capsule()
            .cornerRadius(25)
            .scaleEffect(pulsate ? 1 : 1.2)
            .animation(Animation.easeInOut(duration: 1).repeatForever(autoreverses: true).speed(1.5), value: pulsate)  // <<: here!
            .foregroundColor(Color.red)
            .frame(width: 75, height: 27)
            .onAppear{
                self.pulsate.toggle()
            }
        
        TextField("enter text", text: $stringOfText)
        

        
    }
}
```

Comment: perfect! Thanks so much!